# Is it possible for an object to also be a function?

Tags: javascript

In the vain of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35949554/561731).

Is it at all possible for an object to also be a function.

For example I have the object `person` which is an instance of some object.

Is it possible for me to call `person(...)` and have some return come back to me?

This is where person has **not** been defined as a function to start with.

So for example I have the "class" Person:

```
class Person {
     // .. some class functions
}
```

Then I create a new one

```
let person = new Person();
```

Can I call `person()` and affect the actual object behavior? Or is that not possible at all and `person` itself will have to be defined as a function to begin with?

Comment: you can add properties to a function, which is an object, but you can't call an object.

Comment: @dandavis yes I know that. This is if you have just a an object instance.

Comment: Not yet. Closest you can come AFAIK is to have a custom class inherit from `Function`, ie `myClass extends Function`. NOTE: requires native implementation, so current edge, ff, or chrome only.

Comment: what function would you be calling?

Comment: You want a constructor which produces functions? How would you define the code of the function?

Comment: Try `var fn = function(){alert(fn.item)}; fn.item='hello'; fn();`

Comment: I'm going to go with short answer no on this one. javascript does not allow you to pass parameters to objects, only defined functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an "object" into a function in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124326/how-to-convert-an-object-into-a-function-in-javascript)

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes is it possible to do that and it would affect the values of the `fn` object itself? and can you pass vars?

Comment: @Hatchet I updated my question with more explanation.

Comment: @dandavis I updated my question with more of an explanation of what I mean.

Comment: I don't think you can alter [[Call]] after object creating. It's not an invariant, though, so not completely impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, <strike>No</strike>. Yes! See proxy solution below.

In section [9.2.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist) of the spec it outlines Function objects' internal `[[Call]]` property that allows that object to be called as a function. There is currently no way I know of to modify that property, i.e. make an object into a function after its creation. It will be possible with a fully compliant implementation of ES 2015 to subclass Function and have callable objects (currently works in FF, for example). Even then, I didn't try anything more than making a paper-thin layer over the Function constructor itself. However, ES 2015 also includes [Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), and one of the proxy traps is 'apply'.

```
class Person {
  constructor(arg, body) {
    this.fn = function(a) { this.a = a; };
    return new Proxy(this, {
      apply: function(target, thisArg, args) {
        return target.fn.apply(target, args);
      }
    });
  }
}
var person = new Person();
person(3);
person.a; //3
```

Tested in Chrome 49. Fails in FF unless Person extends Function and makes a call to super:

```
class Person extends Function {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.fn = function(a) { this.a = a; };
    return new Proxy(this, {
      apply: function(target, thisArg, args) {
        return target.fn.apply(target, args);
      }
    });
  }
}
var person = new Person();
person(3);
person.a;
```

According to MDN, the part about requiring the `super` call is correct at least (for subclasses) but I am unsure whether Proxies should let you call a non-function the way chrome lets you.

### UPDATE

I opened another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36090087/do-proxies-enable-calling-a-non-function) about which behavior is correct. For those too lazy to follow a hyperlink the calling of a non-function is a bug in some specific versions of chrome that has since been fixed.

Comment: Updated the question with more explanation.

Comment: Hmm interesting. Is it even possible to extend `Function`?

Comment: This is a very cool answer. It would be interesting to try to figure our how to extend `Function` but to keep some `this` binding intact without the extra magic

Comment: @Neal it is possible with a native es 2015 class implementation (current chrome, ff, edge). As for the `this` part, you might be able to work it with a bound call to `super`.

Comment: Never mind about super. Updated answer to include a solution using proxies.

Comment: Jared -- with this solution however (with the proxys) Can I have other functions a part of the `Person` class? or would they all have to be defined in the proxy?

Comment: @Neal no the proxy simply wraps an object (in this case, a function object). So a person could be both a function and an object with methods. You can even assign values (including methods) after initialization, the Proxy will pass through to the underlying object any operations it doesn't have a trap set for (including assgnment).